# How can I export nsys' output qdrep files?

Tags: sqlite, cuda, nsight-systems

I've run NSight Systems' command-line variant,  `nsys` to profile an app; and it generated a `.qdrep` file. The profiling can be run with `-export=sqlite`, to also get a nicely-readable sqlite database as the output, but - this didn't happen in my case.

Is there some command-line, non-GUI tool I could use to export the `.qdrep` file I have into a more accessible format? I know that when actually profiling, I can have `nsys` produce an sqlite file itself, so converting .qdrep to sqlite would be nice; but anything else is also acceptable.

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-systems/UserGuide/index.html#cli-stats-command-switch-options

Comment: @RobertCrovella: But I don't want to  / can't perform the profiling again. Also, clarified I want a command-line tool.

Comment: You may wish to read the section I linked carefully.  What I linked is a command line tool and it doesn't require you to perform the profiling again.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Yes, you're right. Made that into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1: The `nsys stats` command

The `stats` command of NSight Systems is actually *not* intended for exporting .qdrep's to SQLite format, but rather to generate statistics of some kind *using* an SQLite database. However, it turns out that if you have a .qdrep but no SQLite, it will export the former into the latter before doing the rest of the work. So, this may work:

```
nsys stats report.qdrep
```

Caveat: Haven't tried it myself yet.

#### Option 2: `nsys-exporter`

There's a utility which is bundled with NSight Systems, named `nsys-exporter`. While it is clearly marked as a "beta tool" - what is life but a beta, right? So you could write:

```
nsys-exporter -s report.qdrep report.sqlite
```

and it will work. There are additional export formats: Text, JSON, HDF5 (but they might not be exactly what you expect - try and see what exactly comes out.)